# How can I get the font family name from a .ttf file in golang?

Tags: go, fonts, truetype

As we know, a `.ttf`(or `otf`) font file's file name is not always the same with the font family name, for example, if I rename `Arial.ttf` to `abcd.ttf`, it's font family name is still Arial, so is there a package or library in golang to parse `.ttf` and get that name?

I've tried [freetype](https://github.com/golang/freetype), but it seems no method can get it

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/golang/freetype"
)

func main() {
    homeDir, _ = os.UserHomeDir()
    fontFile := homeDir + "/Downloads/New Folder With Items 5/Arial.ttf"
    fontBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fontFile)
    font, err := freetype.ParseFont(fontBytes)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(font)
    }
}
```

[image]

There are few methods of `*truetype.Font`

> Name returns the Font's name value for the given NameID

Where can I the the `NameID`?
[image]

---

**Edit:**

It turns out that `NameID` is a go constant that represents a `field` of the TrueType font attributes, I found that the value of `NameIDPostscriptName` field will be used as font unique name, for example, a `.fcpxml` file will use this value as it's font name

The following snippet can get the unique font name of a `.ttf` file

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    // the original freetype has a bug for utf8: https://github.com/golang/freetype/issues/66
    // "github.com/golang/freetype"

    // so we use this beta one
    "github.com/beta/freetype"
    "github.com/beta/freetype/truetype"
)

// getPostscriptName returns the PostscriptName of a .ttf font file
func getPostscriptName(fontFilePath string) (postscriptName string, err error) {
    postscriptName = ""
    fontBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fontFilePath)
    if err == nil {
        font, err := freetype.ParseFont(fontBytes)
        if err == nil {
            postscriptName = font.Name(truetype.NameIDPostscriptName)
        }
    }
    return postscriptName, err
}

func main() {
    fontFileRelative := "Downloads/New Folder With Items 5/Arial.ttf"
    homeDir, _ := os.UserHomeDir()
    fontFile := filepath.Join(homeDir, fontFileRelative)

    postscriptName, _ := getPostscriptName(fontFile)
    fmt.Println(postscriptName)
}
```

---

**Edit2:**

freetype not supporting otf file, after googling, I found we can use [sfnt](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/image/font/sfnt) to get all the metas of a `.ttf` or an `.otf` font file

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "golang.org/x/image/font/sfnt"
)

func main() {
    fontFile := "/path/to/Arial.ttf"
    nameIDs, err := getFntNameIDs(fontFile)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(nameIDs["NameIDPostScript"])
        fmt.Println("-------------------------")
        prettyPrint(nameIDs)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

// prettyPrint print map or slice as formatted json
func prettyPrint(v interface{}) (err error) {
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(v, "", "  ")
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(b))
    }
    return
}

// getFntNameIDs returns .ttf or .otf font NameIDs
// inspired by https://github.com/wayneashleyberry/sfnt
func getFntNameIDs(fontFile string) (NameIDInfo map[string]string, err error) {

    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fontFile)
    if err != nil {
        return NameIDInfo, err
    }

    f, err := sfnt.Parse(b)
    if err != nil {
        return NameIDInfo, err
    }

    nameIDs := []sfnt.NameID{
        sfnt.NameIDCopyright,
        sfnt.NameIDFamily,
        sfnt.NameIDSubfamily,
        sfnt.NameIDUniqueIdentifier,
        sfnt.NameIDFull,
        sfnt.NameIDVersion,
        sfnt.NameIDPostScript,
        sfnt.NameIDTrademark,
        sfnt.NameIDManufacturer,
        sfnt.NameIDDesigner,
        sfnt.NameIDDescription,
        sfnt.NameIDVendorURL,
        sfnt.NameIDDesignerURL,
        sfnt.NameIDLicense,
        sfnt.NameIDLicenseURL,
        sfnt.NameIDTypographicFamily,
        sfnt.NameIDTypographicSubfamily,
        sfnt.NameIDCompatibleFull,
        sfnt.NameIDSampleText,
        sfnt.NameIDPostScriptCID,
        sfnt.NameIDWWSFamily,
        sfnt.NameIDWWSSubfamily,
        sfnt.NameIDLightBackgroundPalette,
        sfnt.NameIDDarkBackgroundPalette,
        sfnt.NameIDVariationsPostScriptPrefix,
    }

    labels := []string{
        "NameIDCopyright",
        "NameIDFamily",
        "NameIDSubfamily",
        "NameIDUniqueIdentifier",
        "NameIDFull",
        "NameIDVersion",
        "NameIDPostScript",
        "NameIDTrademark",
        "NameIDManufacturer",
        "NameIDDesigner",
        "NameIDDescription",
        "NameIDVendorURL",
        "NameIDDesignerURL",
        "NameIDLicense",
        "NameIDLicenseURL",
        "NameIDTypographicFamily",
        "NameIDTypographicSubfamily",
        "NameIDCompatibleFull",
        "NameIDSampleText",
        "NameIDPostScriptCID",
        "NameIDWWSFamily",
        "NameIDWWSSubfamily",
        "NameIDLightBackgroundPalette",
        "NameIDDarkBackgroundPalette",
        "NameIDVariationsPostScriptPrefix",
    }

    NameIDInfo = map[string]string{}
    for i, nameID := range nameIDs {
        label := labels[i]

        value, err := f.Name(nil, nameID)
        if err != nil {
            NameIDInfo[label] = ""
            continue
        }

        NameIDInfo[label] = value
    }

    return NameIDInfo, err
}
```

Output

```json
ArialMT
-------------------------
{
  "NameIDCompatibleFull": "",
  "NameIDCopyright": "© 2006 The Monotype Corporation. All Rights Reserved.",
  "NameIDDarkBackgroundPalette": "",
  "NameIDDescription": "",
  "NameIDDesigner": "Monotype Type Drawing Office - Robin Nicholas, Patricia Saunders 1982",
  "NameIDDesignerURL": "",
  "NameIDFamily": "Arial",
  "NameIDFull": "Arial",
  "NameIDLicense": "You may use this font to display and print content as permitted by the license terms for the product in which this font is included. You may only (i) embed this font in content as permitted by the embedding restrictions included in this font; and (ii) temporarily download this font to a printer or other output device to help print content.",
  "NameIDLicenseURL": "",
  "NameIDLightBackgroundPalette": "",
  "NameIDManufacturer": "The Monotype Corporation",
  "NameIDPostScript": "ArialMT",
  "NameIDPostScriptCID": "",
  "NameIDSampleText": "",
  "NameIDSubfamily": "Regular",
  "NameIDTrademark": "Arial is a trademark of The Monotype Corporation in the United States and/or other countries.",
  "NameIDTypographicFamily": "",
  "NameIDTypographicSubfamily": "",
  "NameIDUniqueIdentifier": "Monotype:Arial Regular:Version 5.01 (Microsoft)",
  "NameIDVariationsPostScriptPrefix": "",
  "NameIDVendorURL": "",
  "NameIDVersion": "Version 5.01.2x",
  "NameIDWWSFamily": "",
  "NameIDWWSSubfamily": ""
}
```

And actually softwares will use `NameIDFamily` and `NameIDTypographicSubfamily` as the `font` attribute, not `NameIDPostscriptName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to read the data of a ttf file with this go library [freetype](https://github.com/golang/freetype), you just need to provide the font data and it will parse all the data. There is also an article about reading ttf files content manually with javascipt [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/?id=143).

Edit: If you are using freetype to get the family name or other information, you can use the Name reciever function of the struct, it accepts a NameId which is an alias for uint16. (You can find the complete table of the valid value [here](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6name.html) in the name id codes section)

for example, you can get the font family name by using the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/golang/freetype"
)

func main() {
    fontFile := "./font.ttf"
    fontBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fontFile)
    font, err := freetype.ParseFont(fontBytes)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(font.Name(1))
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I've tried freetype before, it seems have no method to get font family name, I've update my question, you can take a look.

Comment: @Willis, thanks for the update, i have updated the anwser too to include more info

Comment: Thank you, actually I've just figure it out myself, and I'm writing an example, actually your code has two problem, the first one is we should use `github.com/beta/freetype` instead of `github.com/golang/freetype`(see my update to know why), the second is, you should use `truetype.NameIDFontFamily` instead of the hard code number "1"

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'm not aware to the bug yet and i just know that they did create an abstraction for the name id.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: hello, I found that freetype not supporting `.otf` font(throw an error: "freetype: invalid TrueType format: bad TTF version"), do you know if there is another package can support `.otf` font?

Comment: I figure it out, you can take a look at my update "Edit2" above

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use third-party packages; you can directly parse binary files. The [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff#table-directory) of TTF and OTF are the same, only the tables may differ (OTF mainly adds [CFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff)).

The following example takes [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#platform-ids), [Unicode BMP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#windows-encoding-ids), which corresponds to platformID, platEncID: 3, 1, as an example to obtain [FamimlyID=1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#name-ids).

```golang
type TableHeader struct {
    SFNTVersion   uint32
    NumTables     uint16
    SearchRange   uint16
    EntrySelector uint16
    RangeShift    uint16
}

type TableRecord struct {
    Tag      [4]byte
    CheckSum uint32
    Offset   uint32
    Length   uint32
}

type TTFont struct {
    TableHeader
    TableRecords []TableRecord
}

type NameTable struct {
    Version       uint16
    Count         uint16
    StorageOffset uint16
    NameRecords   []NameRecord
}

type NameRecord struct {
    PlatformID   uint16
    PlatEncID    uint16
    LangID       uint16
    NameID       uint16
    Length       uint16
    StringOffset uint16
}

func main() {
    var bs []byte
    var font TTFont
    // get font
    bs, _ = os.ReadFile(
        filepath.Join(os.Getenv("windir"), "Fonts/arial.ttf"),
    )
    r := bytes.NewReader(bs)

    // read header
    _ = binary.Read(r, binary.BigEndian, &font.TableHeader)
    font.TableRecords = make([]TableRecord, font.NumTables)

    // read tableReocrd
    _ = binary.Read(r, binary.BigEndian, &font.TableRecords)

    // find nameRecord
    nameIdx := slices.IndexFunc(font.TableRecords, func(r TableRecord) bool {
        return r.Tag == [4]byte{'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'}
    })
    if nameIdx == -1 {
        log.Println("name table not exists")
        return
    }
    nameRecord := font.TableRecords[nameIdx]

    // get nameRawData
    r.Seek(int64(nameRecord.Offset), io.SeekStart)
    nameRawData := make([]byte, nameRecord.Length)
    binary.Read(r, binary.BigEndian, nameRawData)

    nameReader := bytes.NewReader(nameRawData)

    var nameTable NameTable
    // parse name table
    binary.Read(nameReader, binary.BigEndian, (*[3]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&nameTable.Version)))
    nameTable.NameRecords = make([]NameRecord, nameTable.Count)
    binary.Read(nameReader, binary.BigEndian, nameTable.NameRecords)

    // Search for the desired nameID
    // Windows
    const FamilyNameID = 1
    targetIdx := slices.IndexFunc(nameTable.NameRecords, func(nR NameRecord) bool {
        return nR.PlatformID == 3 && // windows
            nR.PlatEncID == 1 && // Unicode BMP
            nR.LangID == 0x409 && // English/United States // 1033
            nR.NameID == FamilyNameID // 1
    })
    if targetIdx == -1 {
        log.Println("3.1.1033.1 not found")
        return
    }
    nR := nameTable.NameRecords[targetIdx]
    nameReader.Seek(int64(nameTable.StorageOffset+nR.StringOffset), io.SeekStart)
    stringRawData := make([]byte, nR.Length)
    binary.Read(nameReader, binary.BigEndian, stringRawData)

    // since PlatformID.PlatEncID 3.0 use UTF16BE
    d := make([]uint16, len(stringRawData)/2)
    for i := range d {
        d[i] = binary.BigEndian.Uint16(stringRawData[2*i:])
    }
    familyName := utf16.Decode(d)
    fmt.Printf("3.1.1033.1: %s\n", string(familyName))

    // example: Mac
    targetIdx = slices.IndexFunc(nameTable.NameRecords, func(nR NameRecord) bool {
        return nR.PlatformID == 1 && // Mac
            nR.PlatEncID == 0 &&
            nR.LangID == 0 && // english
            nR.NameID == FamilyNameID // 1
    })
    if targetIdx == -1 {
        log.Println("1.0.0.1 not found")
        return
    }
    nR = nameTable.NameRecords[targetIdx]
    nameReader.Seek(int64(nameTable.StorageOffset+nR.StringOffset), io.SeekStart)
    stringRawData = make([]byte, nR.Length)
    binary.Read(nameReader, binary.BigEndian, stringRawData)

    // https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/ROMAN.TXT
    // var romanTable = []rune("ÄÅÇÉÑÖÜáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûü†°¢£§•¶ß®©™´¨≠ÆØ∞±≤≥¥µ∂∑∏π∫ªºΩæø¿¡¬√ƒ≈∆«»… ÀÃÕŒœ–—“”‘’÷◊ÿŸ⁄€‹›ﬁﬂ‡·‚„‰ÂÊÁËÈÍÎÏÌÓÔÒÚÛÙıˆ˜¯˘˙˚¸˝˛ˇ")
    // romanDecoder := macDecoder(romanTable)
    xMacEnglishDecoder := macDecoder(nil)
    bsFamilyName, _ := xMacEnglishDecoder(stringRawData)
    fmt.Printf("1.0.0.1: %s\n", bsFamilyName)
}

func macDecoder(table []rune) func([]byte) ([]byte, error) {
    return func(bytes []byte) ([]byte, error) {
        var str string
        for _, c := range bytes {
            if c <= 0x7F {
                str += string(c)
            } else {
                if int(c&0x7F) < len(table) {
                    str += string(table[c&0x7F])
                } else {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("%d >= len(table) = %d", c&0x7F, len(table))
                }

            }
        }
        return []byte(str), nil
    }
}
```

<kbd>[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/lcb3IYZGYom)</kbd>

The langID is mainly used in PlatformID=1 (Mac), encID=0 cases. For Mac encoding, you may need to refer to tables, table reference link.

> https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/

There are many other parts I haven't listed, such as decoding [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters), but I believe this is enough to get started. If interested, you can delve deeper into the research.

The code above for [TTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otff#ttc-header) is not applicable, but TTC is not very complex either; it can be seen as a collection of TTFs.